# Height of match_parent not appearing for WebView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

My WebView can only appear if i set an specific height for example 300dp but does not work for match_parent. I know that is bad to set a specific value for height because devices can change in size.
This is my code:

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/campaign_mood_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:ignore="WebViewLayout">

        <br.test.android.presentation.utils.WebViewYouTubePlayer
            android:id="@+id/campaign_video_mood"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/campaign_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/place_holder_drawable"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:transitionName="@string/campaign_image" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, if you want to set `layout_height="match_parent"` to your WebView, its parent FrameLayout's layout_height also should be `match_parent` (or whatever other than `wrap_content`).

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/campaign_mood_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:ignore="WebViewLayout">
```

Also deleting `android:visibility="gone"` is required.

```
<br.test.android.presentation.utils.WebViewYouTubePlayer
            android:id="@+id/campaign_video_mood"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but i still can't see it

Comment: @Gabriel I noticed your WebViewYouTubePlayer's `android:visibility="gone"`. You should remove it (updated my answer).

Comment: I need to explain something. This visibility gone is because it should only appear if there is a video.

Comment: But in my case i added a video but it only appears when i changed the height to 300dp

Comment: @Gabriel Then, you can use `View.INVISIBLE`.

Comment: But even removing this attribute i can't see it. So i don't think is that.